# How do I add Window Manager From Scratch (WMFS) to the Window Manager selection in the login screen?

Tags: window-manager

how do I add Window Manager From Scratch (WMFS) to the Window Manager selection in the login screen?

I've installed it already and now I want to boot it, but how do I do that?

Regards,

Senad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ubuntu wiki:

> Ubuntu 12.04 uses LightDM by default.
>
> Create a new file /usr/share/xsessions/custom.desktop with:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Name=Xsession
> Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
> ```
>
> You should now have a new session option during login, Xsession will load the user's ~/.xsession file

The above allows you to create and use a .xsession file in your home directory. So now you should create said .xsession file and put the following in it:

```
exec wmfs
```

Then from the login screen you should see a new entry, log in with that and (hopefully) you should see your new, highly minimal window manager. Enjoy!